# eclipse for c++ developers MinGW error

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I just installed the Eclipse for C++ Developers, but my problem is that it does not recognize MinGW (MinGW is in the System Environment Variables, if i open CMD where ever it runs `gcc --version` just fine)
in eclipse settings under C++ i have the environment variables set also..
but when i open new c++ project nothing gets recognized (libraries, syntax, etc..) and my only toolchain available is Cross GCC witch i do not have installed.. 
CodeBlocks works fine with C++
but i want to try eclipse..

Comment: Which variant of mingw? I've had trouble getting it to recognize some of the newer ones.

Comment: the read me says this:
[CONTENTS]
Essentials:
    * binutils 2.28
    * GCC 7.1.0
    * mingw-w64 5.0.2
its the latest one to my knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by putting mingw32-gcc.exe in the bin folder..
in other words.. eclipse needs the 32bit version of minwg..